# unwanted \ character

Tags: php

php code:

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(glob("photos-".$_GET["folder"].'/*.jpg'));
?>
```

it return :

```
["photos-animaux\/ani-01.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-02.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-02b.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-03.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-04.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-05.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-06.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-07.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-08.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-09.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-10.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-11.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-12.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-13.jpg","photos-animaux\/ani-14.jpg"]
```

Which is ALMOST perfect, except for the \ character... Where did it come from?

Here is the jquery code that calls it:

```
$.get(  'photolister.php',
                    {'folder' : $(this).attr('href')},
                    function(data){startSlideshow(data);console.log(data);}
                );
```

Comment: I'm curious - what is the contents of `$_GET["folder"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is automatically escaping the string.

You can use stripslashes to remove the unwanted slashes.

You could also use the GLOB_NOESCAPE flag in your glob() call.

[PHP Manual: stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)
[PHP Manual: glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: Possibly. But I would check the contents of $_GET["folder"] first, then check this out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's escaping the '/' out?

anyways, it shouldn't matter, when JS parses the json, it probably will ignore it...